# Host 'host_name' is blocked because of many connection errors. Unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

I'm getting following message:

> Host 'host_name' is blocked because of many connection errors. Unblock
>   with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

I've tried to follow [MySQL :: MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual :: B.6.2.5 Host 'host_name' is blocked](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blocked-host.html) like so, yet without success(

```
# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
# mysqladmin flush-hosts
# echo $?
0
# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2221
Server version: 5.1.73-log Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> FLUSH HOSTS;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> Bye
#
```

I even tried to restart mysqld, still getting same message(

Please advise.

Comment: are you getting same result when you try with: "mysqladmin flush-hosts -u [username] -p" directly from command line ?

Comment: @Jay I haven't tried your method, but I assume it'd be exactly the same, as I have `~/.my.cnf` (which contains username and password).

Comment: You probably need to connect as user "root" or some other `SUPER` user.

Comment: Maybe the host gets blocked again right after you flush it?

Comment: @RickJames as I mentioned, I already use that as `~/.my.cnf` contains root credentials, which has `SUPER` privilege.

Comment: @eckes unlikely as I even tried following: `watch -n 1 'mysqladmin flush-hosts ; echo $?'` - which runs `mysqladmin flush-hosts` every second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue with following:

```
# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 216305
Server version: 5.1.73-log Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SET GLOBAL max_connect_errors=10000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> Bye
#
```

I'm not entirely sure, if that actually what addressed my issue, however after above SQL statement, my app started to work (without being blocked anymore).